# Valor Final do array?

Tags: php, array

Essa minha váriavel:

```
 $valor = $cliente->cobrancas[1]->valor;
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($cliente);
 echo '<pre>';
```

Imprime os valores abaixo:

```
  stdClass Object
  (
[id] => 24151
[nome] => PAULO ANDRE ROCHA MOTTA
[endereco] => RUA CARMELA DUTRA 400 APTO 301 
[bairro] => AGRIOES
[cidade] => TERESOPOLIS
[cep] => 25963140
[uf] => RJ
[pontos] => 0
[indicados] => Array
    (
    )


[cobrancas] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 527561
                [nossonumero] => 3045835
                [dataemissao] => 1346900400
                [datavencimento] => 1347246000
                [datapagamento] => 1347246000
                [dias_vencidos] => 1344
                [mora] => 0.53651612903226
                [multa] => 4.158
                [valor] => 207.90
                [valorpago] => 196.47
                [valordesconto] => 10.00
                [jurosmora] => 0.00
                [banco] => 33
                [agencia] => 1525
                [dac_agencia] => 0
                [conta] => 013000045
                [dac_conta] => 2
                [carteira] => 201
                [nome_empresa] => STOCK MIDIA INF. LTDA
                [cod_cedente] => 1640348
            )

        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 527562
                [nossonumero] => 3045836
                [dataemissao] => 1346900400
                [datavencimento] => 1349406000
                [datapagamento] => 1349406000
                [dias_vencidos] => 1319
                [mora] => 0.30425806451613
                [multa] => 2.358
                [valor] => 117.90
                [valorpago] => 106.47
                [valordesconto] => 10.00
                [jurosmora] => 0.00
                [banco] => 33
                [agencia] => 1525
                [dac_agencia] => 0
                [conta] => 013000045
                [dac_conta] => 2
                [carteira] => 201
                [nome_empresa] => STOCK MIDIA INF. LTDA
                [cod_cedente] => 1640348
            )

        [2] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 527563
                [nossonumero] => 3045837
                [dataemissao] => 1346900400
                [datavencimento] => 1352080800
                [datapagamento] => 1352080800
                [dias_vencidos] => 1288
                [mora] => 0.30425806451613
                [multa] => 2.358
                [valor] => 117.90
                [valorpago] => 106.47
                [valordesconto] => 10.00
                [jurosmora] => 0.00
                [banco] => 33
                [agencia] => 1525
                [dac_agencia] => 0
                [conta] => 013000045
                [dac_conta] => 2
                [carteira] => 201
                [nome_empresa] => STOCK MIDIA INF. LTDA
                [cod_cedente] => 1640348
            )

        [3] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 527564
                [nossonumero] => 3045838
                [dataemissao] => 1346900400
                [datavencimento] => 1354672800
                [datapagamento] => 1354672800
                [dias_vencidos] => 1258
                [mora] => 0.30425806451613
                [multa] => 2.358
                [valor] => 117.90
                [valorpago] => 106.47
                [valordesconto] => 10.00
                [jurosmora] => 0.00
                [banco] => 33
                [agencia] => 1525
                [dac_agencia] => 0
                [conta] => 013000045
                [dac_conta] => 2
                [carteira] => 201
                [nome_empresa] => STOCK MIDIA INF. LTDA
                [cod_cedente] => 1640348
            )

        [4] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 527565
                [nossonumero] => 3045839
                [dataemissao] => 1346900400
                [datavencimento] => 1357351200
                [datapagamento] => 1357524000
                [dias_vencidos] => 1227
                [mora] => 0.30425806451613
                [multa] => 2.358
                [valor] => 117.90
                [valorpago] => 106.47
                [valordesconto] => 10.00
                [jurosmora] => 0.00
                [banco] => 33
                [agencia] => 1525
                [dac_agencia] => 0
                [conta] => 013000045
                [dac_conta] => 2
                [carteira] => 201
                [nome_empresa] => STOCK MIDIA INF. LTDA
                [cod_cedente] => 1640348
            )
```

Como posso fazer com que a função imprima sempre e somente o último `valor` ???

Answer (score 2):

Use a função `end` para pegar o último valor do `array`.

```
 $valor = end($cliente->cobrancas)->valor;
```

Eu, por precaução, tomaria o cuidado de verificar se aquele valor realmente é um objeto.

```
$ultima_cobranca = end($cliente->cobrancas);

if ($ultima_cobranca instanceof \stdClasss)
{
   print_r($ultima_cobranca->valor);
}
```

Comment: Pensei no `end()` mas nem lembrava que ele retornava o último elemento, lembrei que setava o ponteiro pro final. +1

Comment: Obrigado funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Se quer apenas pegar o valor da chave `valor` desse array, use a função `array_pop()` ela extrair e remove o último do array passado. Caso precise listar cada elemente use um foreach.

```
$ultimo = array_pop($cliente->cobrancas);
echo $ultimo->valor;
```

Comment: O único problema do `array_pop` é que ele remove o último elemento do `array`. Pode ser que o AP queira que o array continue intacto  (mas ele não falou isso na pergunta mesmo)